# Можно ли в конструкции switch использовать интервал вместо одного значения?

Tags: eclipse, switch, java

Можно ли использовать, например, вместо

```
switch(n){
  case 1:
  case 2:
  ...
  case 99:
  case 100:
  System.out.println('Числа от 1 до 100');
  break;
  ...
}
```

использовать

```
switch(n){
  case 1..100:
  System.out.println('Числа от 1 до 100');
  break;
  ...
}
```

Или что-то типо того...
Если можно то как?

Comment: нет. Только цепочки if'ов

Comment: добавлю только, что можно реализовать ИЛИ кейсами

Comment: Вы ошиблись языком: вам нужен Паскаль или [Перл](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html).

Comment: Есть ещё табличный метод. Правда он хорош, если диапазоны не очень большие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так?

```
 private int checkValue(int value) {
   final Integer values1[]={1,2,5,6,0};
   final Integer values2[]={4,7,8,9,3};

   if(values1.contains(value))
      return 1;
   else if(values2.contains(value))
      return 2;
   else
     return 0;
 }

 switch(checkValue(value)) {
   case 1: //1,2,5,6,0
      break;
   case 2: //4,7,8,9,3
      break;
   default: //Нет попадания

 }
```

Comment: фигня это =)

Answer (score 5):

Если интервалы одинаковые, то воспользуйтесь таким способом:

```
switch ( (n-1) / 100 ) {
   case 0: break; // 1-100
   case 1: break; // 100-200
   // ...
}
```

Comment: и что так будет работать?

Comment: К сожалению, интервалы не одинаковые(

Comment: @imholynx довольно остроумно, хотя подходит далеко не везде и несколько неочевидно)

Comment: @Gorets, без проблем работает

Comment: а как мне попасть в case 3, 4?

Comment: Не пойму, к чему вы клоните: [Код][1]
[1]: http://ideone.com/2DSU2T

Comment: Ну если учесть, что switch работает итеративно(пробегая по всем сравнениям до брейка), то можно циклом аналог написать...без всяких там извращений...ну это так мое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

зря Вы идею с циклом проигнорировали...по факту схожие вещи...ну или как-то так...

```
public static int getIndex (int arg, int [] lo, int [] hi ) {
    int lenght = (lo.length <= hi.length) ? lo.length : hi.length;
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght ; i++) {
        if (arg >= lo [i] && arg <= hi[i]) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arg = 11;
    int index= getIndex(arg, new int [] {1 , 5, 10, 15} , new int [] {4, 9, 14 , 19});
    System.out.println(index);
}
```